# Parse Server Twitter Authentication

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Im trying to put the pieces together for Parse Servers Twitter Authentication but Im not sure how it works, The documentation here has the following info `https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#twitter-authdata` but theres not so much detailed information about how to actually implement a full twitter auth flow.

I have managed to piece together an expressJS flow but how do I pass sensitive data to cloud functions from the express routes ?

Would really love to see an example of parse/twitter backend flow.

Comment: Take a look at this guide: https://www.back4app.com/docs/javascript/login-twitter

Comment: Yes, but there is a problem with the parse Twitter auth, the way it is done doesnt return the user data - you must supply the auth token and secret which are validated in parses twitter auth, however it does not return the user data and you cannot reuse those tokes again ! I had to write a hack which would bypass the auth adapter with a custom auth then process the twitter user account myself in a similar fashion to how the adapter works but returning the user auth object